# What is the actual Polish street name of the street in Martinau, now Rokitnica, of Strasse der SA?

Tags: nazi-germany, poland, silesia

My mother who was born in [Beuthen/Bytom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytom), but must have lived at least for a while in [Martinau](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rokitnica_(Zabrze)), "Strasse der SA 19". I want to go there and find the street.

Martinau was Rokittnitz (part of the Landkreis Beuthen from 1927 on) and was named Martinau from 1936 until 1945. Rokitnica is now a part of Zabrze (*) I think from 1951 on, according to Wikipedia.

Before my mother married my father in Bytom in the year 1941, she must have lived in Martinau. I have a confirmation of the marriage *(Bescheinigung der Eheschliessung)*, in which her address is given as

> Martinau, Strasse der SA 19.

Please help me to find the actual current Polish name of this street in Rokitnica in [Zabrze](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zabrze), Poland.

(*) Zabrze also named Hindenburg O.S. 1915-1945

[image: Confirmation of Marriage. Bescheinigung der Eheschliessung]

Comment: I need more context to understand this question. Where is Martinau? Is it in [Poland](https://geographic.org/geographic_names/name.php?uni=-733308&fid=4756&c=poland)?  Google gives me StormAbteilung for "SA", and [Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rokitnica) for Rokitnica.   "Strasse" is merely street.  Please clarify Please at least tell us which country?  There is a Martinau in Poland and in Austria, both of which were encompassed by the only tag given (Nazi-Germany).

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Isn't this about a street in Bytom, Martinau just superfluous info?

Comment: The suspicion is now that in Martinau there was no street of that name? Please clarify this with an [edit].

Comment: I still doubt that the smallish settlement had a street of that name. But can you give us the maiden name or better yet a scan of that certificate?

Comment: No no. Martinau is now called Rokitnica as part of Zabrze. It was named in pre-Nazi times Rokittnitz. But the Nazis named it Martinau between 1936 and 1945. I am looking just for a street named Strasse der SA in Martinau (which was not that small as you suggest).

Comment: My mothers maiden name was Skrzipczyk. I can send you the scan of the certificate. The settlement Martinau is not that smallish as you think. And, by the way, it had then a hospital (that still exists, now as part of Zabrze University). My mother was educated as a nurse and it is possible, but I have no other confirmation, that she worked for a while in that hospital.

Comment: I do not know how I can send you a scan of my mother's certificate. Please give me some instruction.

Comment: Ideal would be to scan it, redact any unwanted private info and upload it here with an [edit]. But first, can you confirm that a familiar name is listed [here](https://www.sbc.org.pl/dlibra/show-content/publication/edition/4905?id=4905) on page 146 (or p 184 of the electronic/djvu version)?

Comment: I cannot find my mother's name listed in Martinau. This means that she lived here later than 1937.

Comment: I can find three sisters of my mother in Beuthen, Parkstrasse 1. I know that they lived here since the dead of their parents in order to look over the other children (of 15!). But this does not concern my specific question.

Comment: I think too that in Martinau the street names have changed later than 1937. So we can try to find out when a street in Martinau was named Strasse der SA. On the other hand, also in 1937 there were already typical street names, like with Adolf-Hitler, Dietrich-Eckard and Schlageter- But not Strasse der SA. This must have been later, but when precisely?

Comment: @ChristophSauer I'm flabbergasted that Straße der SA wasn't quickly renamed in July 1934 after the Night of the Long Knives

Answer (score 9):

In [*Beuthen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytom) there was a *Straße der SA*, that is [now *Bytom' ulica Żołnierza Polskiego*](https://bytomski.pl/forum-mobile/historia-miasta-i-zabytki/47787-nazwy-ulic-swiadectwo-historii?start=30) (Street of the Polish soldier):

> [image] [Map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%C5%BBo%C5%82nierza+Polskiego,+41-902+Bytom,+Polen/@50.3504925,18.922424,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4716d33aa8eca0bb:0x209acd9d8c9aa15e!8m2!3d50.3504925!4d18.9246127)

The street was before that the Feldstrasse:

> Bytom, then Beuthen O.S., the SA militia quickly found their place. It was a building existing to this day at 9 Żołnierza Polskiego Street (then a plot of land Vorstadt 317, formerly Feldstrase 1b). From 1923 the house was owned by the widow Atonine Ebet (her husband Otto died during World War I), who later boasted of her merits for the Nazi movement. It was in this building that members of the German organizations Schwarze Schar and Landesschützen gathered as early as 1921. Probably also sympathizers of this movement from nearby towns and villages came here. After that, the building became the first meeting place for members of the Nazi party NSDAP and its militias SA (so-called Sturmlocal). It was in this place that the Bytomian fascist movement was formed. Later, in recognition of the history of this place, the Nazi authorities of Bytom renamed today's Polish Soldier's Street to Strasse der SA, and the building was given number 9. One can expect that the activists of the fascist movement from Piekary knew this place perfectly well, because it was a point of contact for them with their Bytomian principals.
>   [src: Centralne sterowanie 2004](https://docplayer.pl/12401886-Centralne-sterowanie.html)
>
> [image: Wikipedia Beuthen Stadtplan]

And this is a detail [from a](http://igrek.amzp.pl/11769538) [1941 map:](http://maps.mapywig.org/m/City_plans/G%C3%B3rno%C5%9Bl%C4%85ski_Okr%C4%99g_Przemys%C5%82owy/BEUTHEN_O.S_10K_1941.jpg)

> [image]

Combining [Digitale Bibliothek Beuthener Architektur](http://www.architekturabytomia.org/de/planmiasta), which gives you all German names from 1928 (in this case Feldstraße) and current Polish names:

> [image]

you'll [arrive at number 19](http://www.zumi.pl/bytom,namapie.html#50.350978/18.924693/17)

> [image]

Which in 2014 is this:

> [image]

---

The previously Slavic name of the other village slightly to the West in the same county ([50°22'0" N / 18°48'0" E](https://mapcarta.com/18519744)) was renamed between 1935/6 from [Rokittnitz → Martinau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landkreis_Beuthen-Tarnowitz) and now Rokitnica.

Unless clarified by OP, I doubt that [it](http://igrek.amzp.pl/result.php?cmd=pt&locsys=1&uni=-733308&box=0.0001&hideempty=on) also had a street "Straße der SA". That may be an error, but my guess is that the certificate was misread. The woman was born in Rokittnitz/Martinau and then at the time of marriage living at the given address in Beuthen?

The village of Rokittnitz/Martinau is with [7845 inhabitants in 1939](http://treemagic.org/rademacher/www.verwaltungsgeschichte.de/beuthen.html) just a bit too small to be a probable candidate for containing such a street name:

> [image: Map of Rokottnitz 19th cent: https://mapire.eu/en/geoname/poland/rokitnica-3087033/] 
>   [image: Map of Rokittnitz from 1935: http://maps.mapywig.org/m/German_maps/series/100K_KDR_Gross_and_Einheitsblaetter/Eb_118_Lublinitz-Woischnik-Gleiwitz-Beuthen-Katowice_Karte_7_Gleiwitz-Hindenburg_40K_Anl._zur_H.Dv.g.40-118_1935_LoC_U115_.G3_A32.jpg]
>   [image: Map of Martinau 1940]

[Here](https://www.sbc.org.pl/dlibra/show-content/publication/edition/4905?id=4905) is an [address book of Beuthen *and* Martinau, from 1937.](http://adressbuecher.genealogy.net/addressbooks/search) The street in Beuthen was apparently renamed *after* 1937 (?), as there are still people living at the Feldstraße, like [Czerwensky, Peter.](http://adressbuecher.genealogy.net/addressbook/entry/547480ac1e6272f5d205670b) For Martinau as well, there are no entries for "Straße der SA" in 1937. But perhaps OP can find the maiden name of his mother and a 1937 street name address. Alternative versions with some maps at [Martin-Opitz-Bibliothek.](https://martin-opitz-bibliothek.de/de/elektronischer-lesesaal?keyword=0065368)

Comment: I suspected that the street name should be preceded by "ulica", then went into Google Street View and confirmed it by looking at a street sign.  I'll edit this in for you. However, I'm not sure where that link is supposed to go.

Comment: @Spencer What link? The forum link? In it one poster discusses the name change of the street from 45. Was the first breadcrumb I found. Is it not working at all for you or the relevant passage not found easily? (I guess the full gif-map from Beuthener Architektur makes that link less important now?)

Comment: No no, it is not Bytom, I am looking for, I just look for Martinau, today Rokitnica as part of Zabrze, where a street named Strasse der SA would have been existed

Comment: In 1937 no people with my mother's name are found in Martinau, neither the Strasse der SA. This means clearly that my mother came to Martinau later than 1937 (what is very probable) and that the change of streetnames in Martinau was later too. In 1937 there is already een Adolf-Hitler-Straat of Platz, een Dietrich-Eckard-Weg en een Schlageter-Str. But not yet a Strasse der SA.

Comment: Question was about street in Martinau which is now part of Zabrze (not Bytom).